# SAML SSO in asp.net web form

Tags: webforms, single-sign-on, saml

I need to implement SAML SSO in a webb site based on web forms, can someone please show a example of how to that?

Answer (score 0):

You need a [SAML stack](https://medium.com/the-new-control-plane/i-need-a-saml-stack-now-63d9691e2d43) on your client.

Some of the commercial clients have examples of this.

Basically:

- Configure the client-side SAML parameters based on your IDP
- Have a form with a Login button
- When the button is clicked, use the stack to send an AuthnRequest
- This will trigger an IDP login form
- After the user has logged in, the IDP will return to your Assertion Consumer Endpoint with the SAML token
- Use the stack to extract the attributes you need